# How to perform right click using Selenium in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, right-click

I wonder if someone has solution how to perform trivial right click action on any element of DOM. Let's for example do right click on the 'Google Search' button to select 'Save Page As' option.
According to my research it involves  ActionChains. Roughly my code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

br = webdriver.Firefox()
br.get('http://www.google.com')
btn=br.find_element_by_id('qbqfba')
actionChains = ActionChains(br)

actionChains.context_click(btn).perform()
```

The following errors occurs:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.39.0-py2.7.egg/seleniu
m/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: u'Offset within element cannot be scrol
led into view: (50, 14.5): [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLButtonElement]]' ; St
acktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.mouseMove (file:///tmp/tmpuIgKVI/extensions/fxdri
ver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9176)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpuIgKVI/extens
ions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpuIgKVI/extensio
ns/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpuIgKVI/extensions/fxdr
iver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778)
```

Where I get wrong with it? 
p.s. My testing environment is Ubuntu 12.04, just in case is matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute of the *Google Search* button is `gbqfba`, not `qbqfba` (if you are seeing the same google search page I am seeeing):

```
btn = br.find_element_by_id('gbqfba')
#                            ^
```

[image: Google Search button]

Alternatively you can find button by text:

```
br.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[contains(., "Google Search")]')
```

Comment: thanks falsetru. It works perfect. Now is time for another step, how to control right click to perform "save as page"?

Comment: @karolinastamblewska, Press `p` (shortcut key for Save Page as) `actionChains.send_keys('p').perform()`, now it will pop up a save .. dialog.

Comment: @karolinastamblewska, BTW, you can use `br.page_source` to access page's source. If you want to only save the source code of the page, simply save `br.page_source` to a file.

Comment: Many thanks, once again it will be advance my project, which is far beyond google search, however the scrapping method is still similar ;)